# Type inference not working for generic extension method

Tags: c#

```
public class MyTest<T1, T2>
{
}

public static class MyTestExt
{
    public static MyTest<T1, T2> ToTest<T1, T2>(this T1[] array) => new();

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyTest<double, float> x = Array.Empty<double>().ToTest();
    }
}
```

errors with

> The type arguments for method 'MyTest<T1,T2> DPFM.QTG.Optimisation.ADMMisation.MyTestExt.ToTest<T1,T2>(this T1[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Is this a bug? I know that I could make it work by using `T2` in the signature, but I'd rather not create a dummy parameter just for that reason.

Comment: It's not a bug... C# cannot inferrs type by left side use java(:))